# Primality Formula Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, primality-test, distribution-of-primes

### Primality Formula Conjecture

To test any $(6x-1)$ numbers for primality.

$$
4^{3x-1} \bmod (6x-1)
$$

If that is equal to `1` then $(6x-1)$ is prime.

To test any $(6x+1)$ numbers for primality.

$$
4^{3x} \bmod (6x+1)
$$

If that is equal to `1` then $6n+1$ is prime.

I am unsure if this holds true for infinity. I have only tested around 200 numbers by hand. It quickly becomes difficult because of the exponent, and I am also not a professional Mathematician, I just like to play with numbers. So please be patient with me.

#### Backstory

I stumbled upon this while fooling around with numbers and the Collatz conjecture. I was first studying

$$
\frac{3x+1}{2}
$$

After which I became interested in finding what numbers of $x\bmod 6 = 5$ or $x\bmod 6 = 1$ became a power of 2 within the Collatz Conjecture. So I shifted things around a bit and create this formula.

$$
y = \frac{2^{x}-1}{3}
$$

That resulted in this series.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $\frac{1}{3}$ |
| 2 | $1$ |
| 3 | $2\frac{1}{3}$ |
| 4 | $5$ |
| ... | ... |

This was too noisy with fractions every other result, so I removed the noise by using 4.

$$
y = \frac{4^{x}-1}{3}
$$

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $1$ |
| 2 | $5$ |
| 3 | $21$ |
| 4 | $85$ |
| ... | ... |

I then became interested in knowing the factors of those numbers.

| X | Y | Prime Factors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $1$ | 1 |
| 2 | $5$ | 5 |
| 3 | $21$ | 3, 7 |
| 4 | $85$ | 5, 17 |
| 5 | $341$ | 11, 31 |
| 6 | $1365$ | 3, 5, 7, 13 |
| 7 | $5461$ | 43, 127 |
| 8 | $21845$ | 5, 17, 257 |
| 9 | $87381$ | 3, 7, 19, 73 |
| 10 | $349525$ | 5, 11, 31, 41 |
| 11 | $1398101$ | 23, 89, 683 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I then noticed a pattern and created this formula.

$$
\frac{4^{3x-1}-1}{3}
$$

| X | Y | Prime Factors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $5$ | `5` |
| 2 | $341$ | `11`, 31 |
| 3 | $21845$ | 5, `17`, 257 |
| 4 | $1398101$ | `23`, 89, 683 |
| 5 | $89478485$ | 5, `29`, 43, 113, 127 |
| 6 | $22906492245$ | 1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 19, 37, 73, 109 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I noticed when $\frac{4^{3x-1}-1}{3}$ was divisible by $(6x-1)$ then it was a prime number. I then continued testing this conjecture with hundreds of primes. It seemed to work.

I don't know how to go about proving this. I'm not practiced in proofs being just a math hobbyist. It would be amazing to hear your feedback about this conjecture.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Fermat's little theorem says if $6n-1$ is prime then $4^{3n-1}=2^{(6n-1)-1}\equiv1\pmod{6n-1}$

Comment: but there are pseudoprimes like $341=6\times57-1$, which is not prime $(31\times11)$ but $2^{6\times57-2}=4^{3\times57-1}\equiv1\pmod{6\times57-1}$

Comment: The second claim is false for $x=184$, which gives $6x+1=1105=5 \cdot 13 \cdot 17$, a  pseudoprime to base $2$. See https://oeis.org/A001567.

Comment: It is impressive that you stumbled across the notion of a pseudoprime by accident, and realised intuitively that there is a connection to primes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p=6x-1$ is prime,

then by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $4^{3x-1}=2^{6x-2}=2^{(6x-1)-1}\equiv 1\pmod{6x-1}$.

But the converse does not hold for a [pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime) base $2$ such as $341=6\times57-1$:

$4^{3\times57-1}=2^{(6\times57-1)-1}=2^{340}\equiv1\pmod{341=6\times57-1}$,

though $341=11\times31$ is not prime.

Comment: Thanks for help. :)